# Heroku 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In production.rb I have the following single line for config.action_mailer..

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'secret-brushlands-   1375.herokuapp.com' }
```

In Development.rb I have (this seems to work BTW)

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}
```

In Environment.rb I have:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['sendgrid user'],
  :password       => ENV['sendgrid password'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

For some reason I am getting this error with my heroku app (this is only
happening with the users portion when I try to sign_up, the other model
functionality on postgresql seems to be cool) - I have done a heroku
pg:reset
heroku run rake:db:migrate, etc.. but to no avail.

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

gem 'pg'


gem 'foundation-rails'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production


gem 'devise'


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'



gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc



gem 'tzinfo'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

And here is the heroku log:

```
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.598955+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in
    with_transact
    ion_returning_status'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.598952+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in
    `save'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.598961+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statemen
    ts.rb:211:in `transaction'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.598957+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statemen
    ts.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.598959+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statemen
    ts.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599212+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in
    `with_transaction_retur
    ning_status'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599214+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599209+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599215+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in
    `rollback_active_record
    _state!'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599228+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in
    halting'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599218+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/dev
    ise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in
    `create'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599223+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
    `process_action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599220+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
    `send_action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599231+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in
    halting'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599217+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599224+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in
    process_actio
    n'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599230+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599233+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599227+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599221+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'

    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599225+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599234+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
    halting'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599237+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
    halting'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599239+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599236+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599258+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599262+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in
    halting_and_co
    nditional'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599260+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599263+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599256+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
    halting'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599266+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599265+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in
    halting_and_co
    nditional'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599276+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in
    `process_action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599259+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
    halting'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599268+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599278+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in
    `process_action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599282+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
    `instrum
    ent'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599286+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in
    `process_acti
    on'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599284+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599281+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in
    instrument
    '
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599279+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in
    `block in pro
    cess_action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599322+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in
    `process_
    action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599325+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionview-4.1.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599285+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in
    `process_acti
    on'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599324+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599327+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599332+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599338+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599341+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in
    call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599330+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599329+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in
    `dispatch'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599334+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599345+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599336+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599343+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599347+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599355+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/war
    den-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599357+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/war
    den-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599363+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599353+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/war
    den-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599359+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599369+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599361+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599367+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599370+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599365+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in
    `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599376+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
    b:621:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599372+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599374+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    iverecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599389+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in
    `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599380+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599384+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599382+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599378+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block
    in call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599391+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599386+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in
    `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599393+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599398+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599396+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in
    tagged'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599440+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599488+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599433+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599414+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599400+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599493+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599491+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
    ivesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:
    in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599495+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599497+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599499+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
    lties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599501+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599503+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599502+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
    k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599506+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
    webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599505+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
    webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599509+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599508+00:00 app[web.1]:
    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
    webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.599510+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.588804+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.588813+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to
    tstevens_21@earthlink.
    net (66.7ms)
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.595347+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
    Server Error
     in 389ms
    2014-04-24T17:34:53.600317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
    path=/users
     host=secret-brushlands-1375.herokuapp.com
    request_id=052e3b18-a726-49ae-b816-1b
    b5b13c8367 fwd="216.40.153.100" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=408ms
    status=500
    bytes=1754
```

I am using Devise, and I have installed SendGrid on Heroku. Haven't seen
the email confirmation yet. Any help appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Please share `action_mailer` settings in `production.rb` file.

Comment: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'secret-brushlands-1375.herokuapp.com' }

Comment: Is that all? I don't think so. Give me all the configurations starting with `config.action_mailer` like `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`.. Update it in the question.

Comment: Can't answer my question for 8 hours since I am a newbie :(

Comment: Don't answer, just EDIT your question by clicking on `edit` link underneath the question.

Comment: I hope you have not shared the actual `user_name` and `password` in the question given in the smtp_settings. Did you create an Environment variable named `app24214615@heroku.com` on heroku or is that your REAL user_name?

Comment: If it was your real credentials then go and change your credentials on Heroku, as even if you remove it from question it will still be available in edit history of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `config/environment.rb` file, change the configuration of smtp_settings as below:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],  ## Refer to key SENDGRID_USERNAME
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],  ## Refer to key SENDGRID_PASSWORD
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

After this add the environment variables `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` in heroku environment by running:

```
heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter
```

Comment: Notice the `user_name` and `password` keys. You were specifying it incorrectly.

Comment: Did you do `:user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'], :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],` ? You are not supposed to pass ACTUAL username and password here. Copy the code exactly as shown in my answer. Don't change the values.

Comment: AND VOILA' THERE IT IS - THANK YOU SO MUCH KIRTI !